# How to use VMware Workstation 12 Player as virtual host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, localhost, linux-server

I was trying to set up a virtual linux server (ubuntu) on a windows host using VMWare Workstation 12 Player. The point is to be able to access the server from my browser on windows. The tutorial I am using managed to connect to the guest at localhost (which I have been told is not possible) without much explanation.

I eventually figured it out by connecting via the network adapter ip rather than localhost. See my answer below.

**There are questions similar to this (with better solutions) but solutions for workstation 8 and below don't seem to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Instead I ran a simple server called "http-server" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) and used

`http-server /path/to/index -a 192.xxx.xx.xx -p 3000`

Somehow my instructor managed to do it at localhost but never mind that now. If you are stuck here as I was go to VMware network settings and select custom VMnet1 as a network adapter. Then run ipconfig on the host and get the VMnet1 ip address and connect to it in your browser at 192.xxx.xx.xx:3000 and it should work.

Hopefully this helps but if anyone knows how on the great green earth to get this at localhost please let me know.

EDIT ONE:

Using VMnet1 (host only) settings will not give the server access to the internet but doing the same thing with VMnet8 (NAT) will work better.

EDIT TWO:

See Express as well for essentially the same method but with javascript.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

1. create index.js file with

`var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})
app.listen(3000)`

2. Run `nodejs index.js` on the server OR the way it is called in the Express documentation

   3. go to servers ip address at port 3000 in host browser.